# How to serialize the data to AVRO schema in Spark (with Java)?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs, avro, spark-avro

I have defined an AVRO schema, and generated some classes with avro-tools for the schemes. Now, I want to serialize the data to disk. I found some answers about scala for this, but not for Java. The class `Article` is generated with avro-tools, and is made from a schema defined by me.

Here's a simplified version of the code of how I try to do it:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> filesRDD = context.wholeTextFiles(inputDataPath);
JavaRDD<Article> processingFiles = filesRDD.map(fileNameContent -> {
    // The name of the file
    String fileName = fileNameContent._1();
    // The content of the file
    String fileContent = fileNameContent._2();

    // An object from my avro schema
    Article a = new Article(fileContent);

    Processing processing = new Processing();
    // .... some processing of the content here ... //

    processing.serializeArticleToDisk(avroFileName);

    return a;
});
```

where `serializeArticleToDisk(avroFileName)` is defined as follows:

```
public void serializeArticleToDisk(String filename) throws IOException{
    // Serialize article to disk
    DatumWriter<Article> articleDatumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter<Article>(Article.class);
    DataFileWriter<Article> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<Article>(articleDatumWriter);
    dataFileWriter.create(this.article.getSchema(), new File(filename));
    dataFileWriter.append(this.article);
    dataFileWriter.close();
}
```

where `Article` is my avro schema.

Now, the mapper throws me the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: hdfs:/...path.../avroFileName.avro (No such file or directory)   
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)    
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)     
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)   
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)   
at org.apache.avro.file.SyncableFileOutputStream.<init>(SyncableFileOutputStream.java:60)   
at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.create(DataFileWriter.java:129)
at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.create(DataFileWriter.java:129)
at sentences.ProcessXML.serializeArticleToDisk(ProcessXML.java:207)     
. . . rest of the stacktrace ...
```

although the file path is correct.

I use a `collect()` method afterwards, so everything else within the `map` function works fine (except for the serialization part).

I am quite new with Spark, so I am not sure if this might be something trivial actually. I suspect that I need to use some writing functions, not to do the writing in the mapper (not sure if this is true, though). Any ideas how to tackle this?

**EDIT:**

The last line of the error stack-trace I showed, is actually on this part:

`dataFileWriter.create(this.article.getSchema(), new File(filename));`

This is the part that throws the actual error. I am assuming the `dataFileWriter` needs to be replaced with something else. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe check out the discussions and answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612571/spark-writing-to-avro-file

Comment: I've already seen that one, I was more interested in a Java equivalent. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is not using data-frames and is not throwing any errors:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import scala.Tuple2;

   .  .  .  .  .

// Serializing to AVRO
JavaPairRDD<AvroKey<Article>, NullWritable> javaPairRDD = processingFiles.mapToPair(r -> {    
    return new Tuple2<AvroKey<Article>, NullWritable>(new AvroKey<Article>(r), NullWritable.get());
});
Job job = AvroUtils.getJobOutputKeyAvroSchema(Article.getClassSchema());
javaPairRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(outputDataPath, AvroKey.class, NullWritable.class, AvroKeyOutputFormat.class, 
        job.getConfiguration());
```

where `AvroUtils.getJobOutputKeyAvroSchema` is:

```
public static Job getJobOutputKeyAvroSchema(Schema avroSchema) {
    Job job;

    try {
        job = new Job();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    AvroJob.setOutputKeySchema(job, avroSchema);
    return job;
}
```

Similar things for Spark + Avro can be found here -> https://github.com/CeON/spark-utils.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use Spark in a wrong way.

`Map` is a transformation function. Just calling `map` doesn't invoke calulation of `RDD`. You have to call **action** like `forEach()` or `collect()`.

Also note, that lambda supplied to `map` will be serialized at driver and transferred to some `Node` in a cluster.

**ADDED**

Try to use Spark SQL and [Spark-Avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) to save Spark `DataFrame` in Avro format:

```
// Load a text file and convert each line to a JavaBean.
JavaRDD<Person> people = sc.textFile("/examples/people.txt")
    .map(Person::parse);

// Apply a schema to an RDD
DataFrame peopleDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(people, Person.class);
peopleDF.write()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
    .save("/output");
```

Comment: What are you talking about -- `map` absolutely does invoke calculation of the `RDD`. `map` returns a new `RDD` with all of the elements re-calculated based on the `map` function.

Comment: @Denis Kokorin: I am using `collect()` afterwards, so everything in `map` works already, that's fine. Anything besides the serialization works within the `map` function.

Comment: Perhaps he means you should tack a `foreach` on after the `map` and do your writing there? It might be helpful if this answer had example code.

Comment: @DavidGriffin true that. Denis Kokorin: could you provide an example code maybe? Also, I've updated the question in case you need additional info.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that earlier. But you error points to `hdfs:/...path.../avroFileName.avro`. By default HDFS protocol is not resolved by Java. Try to use Hadoop's FileSystem to open `OutputStream`. Also you definetly should not use `map()` to save something to HDFS. Use either `foreach()` or `store()`.

Comment: @DenisKokorin where is this `store()` function? I cannot find it here on the JavaRDD class https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html To which `store()` are you referring to exactly?

Comment: I have edited my original post. Sorry for been so missleading. I wrote that answer in a hurry.

Comment: @DenisKokorin I actually need a version with whole text file (as in my code), not for the file to be read line by line. Also, the data frame might not be suitable data structure for me, since I have fields which contain multiple elements (arrays). I will try to adjust your suggestion to my needs. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DenisKokorin ok, your suggestion is not working. On the line `DataFrame articleDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(filteredFiles, Article.class);` I get `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. The separate files themselves are not big (couple of hundreds of KBs), so I don't know why this error is thrown. Any way around this method?